# jQuery Validation Error Return a Link

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery Validation Plugin. I have an email field. If the email is in use, I want the validation plugin to give an error with a link to the client's page.

IE: if I input the email john@bobo.com and he is client #312 with the name John Mark, I want my error to be:

`<a href="/index.php?client=312">John Mark</a> is using that email.`

Preferably I would like to have my external file just echo the entire error and have the jQuery Validation plugin to display that full error. If not, I would like to have both the client name and client id to be returned and then be able to output the error message with a link.

jQuery Code:

```
$().ready(function() {
    // Validate the form
    $('#sign-up_area').validate({
      rules: {
        firstName: "required",
        lastName: "required",
        email_address: {
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: "includes/databasecheck.php",
            type: "post",
            success: function(html){
                $("#email").html(html);
            }
        }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstName: "First Name Required",
        lastName: "Last Name Required",
        email_address: {
        email: "Email address need to be valid.",
        //remote: jQuery.format("{0} is taken")
        },
    }
    });
});
```

Form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="sign-up_area">

    <h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Client</h2>

                <fieldset>
                    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="">
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="">
                </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
                    <label for="email_address">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address" value="">
            <div id="email" class="error"></div>
                </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset></form>
```

databasecheck.php

```
<?php
include_once("config.php"); // database connection

if(isset($_POST['email_address'])) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT client_id, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS whole_name FROM client WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email_address']);
    $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($client_id, $whole_name);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo '<a href="/index.php?client='.$client_id.'">'.$whole_name.'</a> is using that email.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation for the Remote Method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), the error message can just be whatever you return from your server.

> The response is evaluated as JSON and **must be true for valid elements**, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; **or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message**.

As long as you construct the custom error message on the server as valid JSON, your code is fine with the message for remote removed...

```
rules: {
    firstName: "required",
    lastName: "required",
    email_address: {
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: "includes/databasecheck.php",
            type: "post",
            success: function(html){
                $("#email").html(html);
            }
        }
    }
},
messages: {
    firstName: "First Name Required",
    lastName: "Last Name Required",
    email_address: {
        email: "Email address need to be valid."
        // The remote error message is coming from the server automatically
        // remote: jQuery.format("{0} is taken")  // <- REMOVE
    },
}
```

Try this PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['email_address'])) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT client_id, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS whole_name FROM client WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email_address']);
    $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($client_id, $whole_name);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $response = '<a href="/index.php?client='.$client_id.'">'.$whole_name.'</a> is using that email.';
    echo json_encode($response);  // failed validation- show the message
} else {
    echo "true";  // passed validation- no message
}
```

See:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Unfortunately when I echo anything other than true, I get the default error message or the error message that I define in the jquery code under "message". I cannot get the desired error I posted above. As such, I cannot pass multiple values back. And I cannot get the error code to include html code.

Comment: @ShawnDibble, it should work as advertised as long as it's valid JSON.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7614020/594235

Comment: Thank you. It is working as desired now. I have been working on that for 2 days and you solved it in 15 minutes.

Comment: Strange bugs have shown up.
1) the form will not validate.
2) The first time it shows an error that is in the database, it gives me a link, however when I back out it sticks until I give an invalid email address . Also at this point, if I give another email already in use, I can't click on the link (the moment I blur that field, the error immediately disappears).

Comment: @ShawnDibble, this sounds like a whole new question.  Please post it as a new question since 'comments' is not a good place for this kind of discussion.

Comment: @ShawnDibble, when you want your `remote` method to pass validation (and clear the message), you must return `true` from your server-side code.  See documentation quoted in top of my answer along with my latest edit.