# Error response from jQuery Validate remote isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the `remote` method of [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to check if a username already exists in the system. The script `does_user_exist.php` returns `1` if the user exists.

```
$registration.find(".username").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.rules('add', {
        remote: {
            url: "does_user_exist.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {uname: function(){ return $this.val(); } },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) { //returns 1 if user exists
                if (data) {
                   console.log("false!");
                   return "Sorry, that user already exists." //doesn't work
                   //return false;        //doesn't work
                   //return data;         //doesn't work
                   //return {"string"};   //doesn't work
                   //return {0: "string"};//doesn't work
                } else {
                   console.log("true!");
                   return true;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            remote: jQuery.format("{0}") //doesn't work
            // remote: "Simple string doesn't work here either"
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that the error message is never displayed. I can see from my `console.log` output that it correctly logs `false!` when the user exists, but the error message never shows up.

As you can see from the commented out lines, I've been trying to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong via guess-and-check, on the assumption that I'm somehow returning the error string in the wrong format, but I'm not having success.

**Edit3:**
I was able to get the backend response to be changed. The PHP is now sending JSON encoded `true`/`false`, to no avail. We have tried sending the backend response in the following ways, but the plugin doesn't seem to be catching it no matter what we do:

```
json_encode( false )
json_encode( '["false"]' )
json_encode( "false" )
json_encode( ["false"] )
"false"
false
NULL
""
0
```

As far as I can tell based on the documentation, one of these should have worked:

> The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements,
>   and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using
>   the default message;

Note, the answer to this question may be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19435906/925897).

Here is the revised code:

```
$registration.find(".username").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    remote: {
        url:  "does_user_exist.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {entityExistence: function(){return $this.val();} },
        success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
    },
    messages: {
        remote: "Sorry, that username is not available."
   }
});
```

The PHP script is always returning `true` or `false` correctly. According to the documentation, anything except for `true` should trigger the error message. But the error message doesn't come up. I know error messaging is working because there are other checks are working fine (e.g. `rangelength`, removed from pasted-in code here for clarity).

Comment: You did not read the documentation for the remote method?  It clearly explains what must be returned by your server code.

Comment: @Sparky: By the way, yes I did read the documentation, specifically [this part](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) of it: _The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message._

Comment: Also quoting: _"must be `true` for valid elements"_ ~ does it return `true` when the user does not exist?  Is your `1` being interpreted as a string or as `true`?  We already know `1` is not _"false, undefined or null"_

Comment: @Sparky Yes, the function returns true `return true;`. It sounds like you're saying that the backend script must return true as well?

Comment: Yes, this is what the documentation is saying.  By "response", it means the response from your server script:  _"The **response** is evaluated as JSON and **must** be `true` for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements..."_

Comment: You don't need to `return` anything in particular via your JavaScript.  The docs are _only_ talking about what comes back from your server.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood that. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: **Quote brentonstrine**:  _"I see, I misunderstood that. Can you post it as an answer?"_ ~ Sure thing.  Posted as answer as you requested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out, randomly. The `success` callback was apparently ruining everything. All I had to do was remove this:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

As soon as I did that, everything worked perfectly as expected using simple string responses:

```
"true"
```

and

```
"false"
```

I can not explain this, but I hope that someone updates the documentation! I noticed that using `complete` does not break it the way that `success` does.

Comment: I also got this to work, by simply having my PHP script `echo "true";` or `echo "false"`.

Comment: The documentation says: "The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be `true`..." but is better to just `echo 'true';` or  `echo 'false';` and forget the JSON part

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/#entry-longdesc) states:

> The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be `"true"` for valid elements, and can be `"false"`, `undefined`, or `null` for invalid elements, using the default error message. If the serverside response is a string, eg. `"That name is already taken, try peter123 instead"`, this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default.

---

**Quote OP:**

> "The script `does_user_exist.php` returns `1` if the user exists."

This might be the opposite of what you want.  Since `1` may be getting interpreted as `true`, which tells the plugin it "passed" validation.  As per docs, if the user exists and you want to trigger an error message, the response must be `false`, `undefined`, `null`, or a string (the message).

Comment: Please see my edit, I was able to change the PHP response, but the same issue is happening.

Comment: @brentonstrine, have you tried `echo "true"`?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18862144/594235

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatley the answers above are slightly cryptic.

In order to get it working you need the follow JS.

```
$('#register-form').validate({
    rules: {
        'first-name': "required",
        'surname': "required",
        'email': {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: 'ajax/users/emailInUse',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $('input[name=email]').val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        'username': "required",
        'password': "required",
        'confirm-password': {
            equalTo: "input[name=password]"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'first-name': "Please enter your first name",
        'surname': "Please enter your surname",
        'email': {
            required: "Please enter your email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email e.g. yoda@jedi.com"
        },
        'username': "Please enter a username",
        'password': "Please enter a password",
        'confirm-password': "Passwords do not match"
    }
});
```

And your backend code should be running the check if the email is valid or not, and return the result as a message within a json string. e.g.

```
[
    " is already in use..."
]
```

Example backend code:

```
public function emailInUseAction()
{

    $this->setJsonResponse();

    if($this->request->isAjax())
    {

        $email = $this->request->getPost('email');

        $emailInUse = Users::emailInUse($email);

        $message = false;

        if($emailInUse)
        {

            $message = $email . ' is already in use...';

        }

        return array(
            $message
        );

    }

}
```

Hope this helps anyone who encounters the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the endpoint to return the validation result as JSON instead of a boolean string like "true" or "false", you can use `dataFilter` to validate the response.

Let's say you have an endpoint to validate if username exists, that returns the result as:

```
{"result": true}
```

You can check the result like this:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 30,
            remote: {
                url: "/validate/username/",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    username: function () {
                        return $("#id_username").val()
                    }
                },
                dataFilter: function (response) {
                    response = $.parseJSON(response);
                    return response.result
                }
            }
        },
        ...
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Returning the string does not automatically display it. If you want to display it you need to do something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').html('<p class="error">Sorry, that user already exists.</p>');
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but I need the validator to handle the error instead of handling it manually. I am integrating it with tooltipster, but beyond that, it doesn't make sense to use a plugin that handles error messages automatically and then circumvent that functionality to do it manually. If I wanted to do it manually, I wouldn't have used the plugin in the first place.