# What is the correct way to format "true" in JSON?

Tags: json, stringify

I want to give a simple `true` response, but according to [various](http://json.parser.online.fr/) [JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) [parsers](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), this is **not** valid JSON:

```
true
```

However, PHP and Javascript act like "true" is indeed valid JSON for `true`, both when encoding and when decoding:

PHP-

```
echo json_encode( true ); // outputs: true
echo json_decode( true ); // outputs: 1
echo gettype(json_decode( true )); // outputs: boolean
```

jQuery-

```
JSON.stringify( true );   // outputs: true
jQuery.parseJSON( true ); // outputs: true
typeof jQuery.parseJSON( true ); // outputs: boolean
```

So what is the correct way to send a `true` response formatted as JSON? Are the validators all wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) :

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = object / array
> ```

Most parsers don't accept anything as root that isn't an object or an array. Only less strict parsers will accept that your JSON string just contains `true`.

So your options are

- to not use JSON
- to wrap your boolean in an object : `{"result":true}` or an array : `[true]`

**Update:**

The situation changed. Newer versions of the JSON specification (see [this one](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)) explicitly accept any serialized value as root of a document:

> A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous
> specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an
> array.  Implementations that generate only objects or arrays where a
> JSON text is called for will be interoperable in the sense that all
> implementations will accept these as conforming JSON texts.

It means it's now legally acceptable to use a boolean as unique value. But of course not all libraries in use are updated, which implies using anything other than an object or an array might still be problematic.

Comment: The form `[true]` seems like it would work for me, but if you feed it to the encode/decode methods, PHP throws this error: `Message : syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'`

Comment: What's the exact PHP code you're using ? You didn't forget the quotes if you're passing it as a literal ?

Comment: Ah yes, that was what I was doing.