# Json.NET boolean JToken cannot deserialize its own serialization

Tags: c#, json.net

When serializing a JToken that simply has a boolean value, the first letter is capitalized. Deserializing the resulting string fails because of that capitalized letter.

The following test fails due to the exception: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0."

```
using System;
using FluentAssertions;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Xunit;

public class SimpleTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestJTokenBoolean()
    {
        var token = JToken.Parse("true");
        token.Type.Should().Be(JTokenType.Boolean);

        Action deserialize = () => JToken.Parse(token.ToString());
        deserialize.Should().NotThrow();
    }
}
```

Am doing something wrong? Or could the possibly be a bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to format "true" in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435906/what-is-the-correct-way-to-format-true-in-json)

Answer (score 3):

I've found the anwer. I was serializing the wrong way. This test works:

```
[Fact]
public void TestJTokenBoolean2()
{
    var token = JToken.Parse("true");
    token.Type.Should().Be(JTokenType.Boolean);

    JToken token2 = null;
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        token.WriteTo(new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter));
        Action deserialize = () => token2 = JToken.Parse(stringWriter.ToString());
        deserialize.Should().NotThrow();

        token2.Type.Should().Be(JTokenType.Boolean);
    }
}
```